# Depth of input validation

Tags: validation

When validating user input how deep would you go?  Let say, that the user provided an ID for a database entity.  The ID is valid in form, like integer, long etc.  But the Entity does not exist in the database.

Should input validation go that deep?

Answer (score 0):

If the entity doesn't exist then trying to access it propably causes some error or exception during execution. So you can check if the ID is valid or manage exception later.